# Integration over finite dimesnional space

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, integration-by-parts

Could someone help me how to get equation (18) from  equation (15)?

[image]

Comment: By means of the integration by parts?

Comment: @KirylPesotski  can you elaborate?